# How to exchange FileOutputStream for BufferedOutputStream

Tags: java, android, xmlserializer, fileoutputstream

I've used this method to serialize an xml file to a SD card

http://www.anddev.org/write_a_simple_xml_file_in_the_sd_card_using_xmlserializer-t8350.html

it works fine but at some point it stops working

The issue is size related, the XML file size I mean

because if I use smaller files it works fine

maybe if i use this method with a BufferedOutputStream instead  of FileOutputStream will work...
but I don't know how to adapt the code for working with buffer

Ant that's my question how to add a buffer to this code.

This is the output log I've got:

```
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279): error occurred while creating xml file
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.getAttributeValue(KXmlParser.java:1303)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at com.digitalnatura.htmlgenereitor.xml2html.serializartodo(xml2html.java:273)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at com.digitalnatura.htmlgenereitor.xml2html.onCreate(xml2html.java:44)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-04 14:06:09.754: ERROR/Exception(2279):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This is clearly a problem with XML encoding, not with the I/O. Your question is fallacious.

Comment: well I asked a clear question, how to change I/O mode, it doesn't matter if  my problem is different. If someone comes to this site and search how to change from FileoutputStream to BufferedOutputStream it will find the answer. One thing is my problem and other is If I made a clear question and found propper answer.

Comment: All the information you posted relates to an XML problem, and one that isn't cured by changing the I/O mode, which in itself is trivial. Your last sentence makes no sense. If your question doesn't relate to your problem then you should reword it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the lines

```
FileOutputStream fileos = null;
// ...
fileos = new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile);
```

with

```
OutputStream fileos = null;
// ...
fileos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile));
```

Comment: how large are the files you're trying to save, and what do you mean by "stop working"? Do you see the "file has been created on SD card" message on the text view?

Comment: no, I've got the exception (line 88) XML files are not that big but I've assumed that the problem was size related because I've tried with smaller pieces of the XML file and everything went fine. ie, if I remove a line serializing goes a line further.

Comment: you may simply be doing something wrong with the serializer. If you change the log message in the code to `Log.e("Exception","error occurred while creating xml file", e);` you'll get the full stack trace and can post that here.

Comment: check your xml is well formed. you're getting an IndexOutOfBounds around xml2html.java line 273. Posting your real source might help.

Comment: xml is well formed, no doubt about that. I know it because if I cut it in smaller pieces,  every single piece of it works. so it's not about xml form. It must be something else.

Comment: Like I said if I delete some lines serialization goes a few lines further, and if I remove quite enough text, it goes to the end

Answer (score 2):

According to the [xmlpull docs](http://www.xmlpull.org/v1/doc/api/org/xmlpull/v1/package-summary.html), the [setOutput function](http://www.xmlpull.org/v1/doc/api/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer.html#setOutput%28java.io.OutputStream%2C%20java.lang.String%29) takes an instance of a Writer-class and a String for encoding as parameters. So instead of using the BufferedOutputStream, you could also use the BufferedWriter. Try to replace the lines 47 and 49 with the following:

```
47  BufferedWriter fileos = null;
49  fileos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newxmlfile));
```

Comment: Do you get any kind of output? Exception/Warnings/Errors?

Comment: yes the one in line 88, but at first with your code in line 57 gave me an error, because fileos was not initialized so i changed line BufferedWriter fileos; for BufferedWritter fileos = null; and then... nothing

Comment: Try `PrintWriter fileos = null;` and `fileos = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newxmlfile)));`

Comment: I've tried what you said but with no luck, second line gaves me an error The constructor PrintWriter(BufferedWriter) is undefined

Comment: The [BufferedWriter doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) initializes an PrintWriter with an instance of BufferedWriter, but the [PrintWriter doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) only mentions the writer class. You could try `fileos = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(newxmlfile));`, but I don't think you gonna have luck with that. And for the log: I can't tell you what the problem is, but there is some Array you are possibly exceeding with *getAttributeValue* in *serializartodo*